# Change Button Width and Height Programmatically Xcocde

Tags: frame, nsbutton

I have an app that you tap a button and at certain points you get time added. I want to add to the app that whenever the certain point is met, the button height and width get smaller. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your button is named, say, `button`, this will make it 5 pixels smaller in all directions:

```
[button setFrame:CGRectInset(button.frame, 5, 5);
```

You can have more freedom by using any `CGRect` value you wish; but `setFrame` is the way to go.